# Using Yield Function in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I want to calculate the Yield To Maturity of a bond using Yield().  Yield() is available in the excel workbook, but I cannot find this function in VBA.

It is not an available WorksheetFunction, nor does it appear as a function in the [atpvbaen.xls] reference.  Does anyone have any suggestions or experience with trying to use Yield() in VBA?

I have tried the following without success:

```
   Dim s as Double
   s = [Yield(settle, maturity, coupon, price, 100,2,1)]
```

The compiler gives me a type mismatch error.

When using:

```
    Debug.Print [Yield(settle, maturity, coupon, price, 100,2,1)]
```

The immediate window shows Error 2029

Comment: What have you tried? A quick [search](https://www.google.com/search?q=Yield()+in+VBA) finds a bunch of links. Have you tried any of those?

Comment: `Debug.Print [Yield(args)]`

Comment: There isn't a clear answer regarding how to utilize Yield() in VBA.

Comment: You know `args` needs to be replaced with the numbers or cell references that contain numbers?  There are 6 required arguments and one optional.

Comment: I understand args are the 6 required inputs, but I receive a type mismatch error when assigning the value of Yield to a double.

Comment: We get so tired of seeing a question asked without example code provided, but in this case it wouldn't help.  The later provided examples even spawned responses to the effect, "you did it wrong," when clearly that was not the case. imho, this post doesn't deserve the neg rep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Yield()` function from older versions of Excel is [no longer available](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/320569-yield-function-visual-basic-applications-2.html). Not even in the *Analysis ToolPak* add-in.

Your best bet would be to create a UDF (user-defined function) in VBA like this:

```
Function YieldToMaturity(Coupon As Currency, FaceValue As Currency, _
Price As Currency, YearsToMaturity As Integer) As Single

YieldToMaturity = (Coupon + ((FaceValue - Price) / YearsToMaturity)) _
/ ((FaceValue + Price) / 2)

End Function
```

Once created you can call the function in a cell in the worksheet by pressing `Shift + F3` and selecting the "User Defined" from the drop-down menu in the Insert Function dialogue box.


**Source:**
[financeformulas.net](http://financeformulas.net/Yield_to_Maturity.html)